# How to display loading widget before local image asset is fully loaded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I want to display a custom widget (may be `CircularProgressIndicator`) before the image file from my local assets (`project_folder/assets/`) fully loaded.

How can I achieve this in Flutter?

I guess using `Timer` for this will work fine, but anyways is there a more reasonable way?

Comment: use `Image.loadingBuilder` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a placeholder, you can try the [FadeInImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) class which may solve yout problem.

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: AssetImage("images/holder.gif"),
  image: AssetImage("images/show.png"),
);
```